# USB 3.0 vs USB 2.0 for external Hard disks drives

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, speed

I considered buying this [HD USB 3.0](http://www.amazon.it/Passport-Hard-Disk-Esterno-SuperSpeed-Nero/dp/B007UOW818/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1382553176&sr=8-1&keywords=western+digital+1tb).

If the writing/reading speed of a HDD is, about, a hundred megabytes per second, it is worth it spending 15€ more for the transfer speed? Isn't it limited by the writing/reading speed? Isn't the USB 2.0 500 mb/s transfer speed enough?

Answer (score 6):

USB 2.0 only has 35MB/s as maximum. In real life 25-30MB/s is realistic. So 100MB/s with USB 3.0 would be worth it for me.

The calculated 60MB/s can't be reached, because USB has a lot of protocol overhead.

Answer (score 1):

A current 2.5" HDD can perform way over 100 MByte/s. [See WesterDigital Red 2.5" (144 MByte/s)](http://www.storagereview.com/wd_red_25_1tb_hdd_review_wd10jfcx)

USB-2.0 HiSpeed offers only 480 Mbit/s = 60 MByte/s (So USB-2.0 is the Bottleneck)

So if you need the HardDrive daily for working then it is of course worth to spend the ridicilous 15€ for the faster performance. If you use the HDD just for backup, then you don't really need it.

Another question is also - do you have a PC with a USB-3.0 Port? If not now, you will have in the near future... **Take the USB-3.0 and enjoy the better performance.**