# USB 2.0 and 3.0 speed comparison for HDD

Tags: hard-drive, usb, synology

So I have a Synology device, with both USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 ports. I wanted to add on additional HDD devices for backing up data. Now my problem is that the USB 3.0 has already been utilized now I am left with only USB 2.0.

My question is how much speed difference would it make? As far as I know the USB 3.0(4800mbps) is ten times faster than USB 2.0(480mbps), but again, the hard disk is a standard one with a write speed of only around 100mbps. So would it make any speed difference if I plug in either ports?

Comment: Another option is to use a small USB3.0 hub.

Comment: Have you seen https://superuser.com/questions/664397/usb-3-0-vs-usb-2-0-for-external-hard-disks-drives ?

Comment: Note the difference between bit and byte.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [USB 3.0 vs USB 2.0 for external Hard disks drives](https://superuser.com/questions/664397/usb-3-0-vs-usb-2-0-for-external-hard-disks-drives)

Comment: **There will be a substantial speed difference.**  Keep in mind, the speed of USB 3.0 (500 MB/s), does not even get near the typical speed of a SATA III mechanical HDD (600 MB/s). All USB HDDs are actually SATA IIII on the surface.  In theory they could be SAS but that would offer little performance gain.  The numbers I have provided are maximum speeds.  There are overheads that are not even considered. SATA III maximum speeds were not typically reached unless the system had a huge amount of cache (or something like an Optane drive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re confusing Megabit and Megabyte. USB 3.0 does 5000 Megabit/s, USB 2.0 does 480 Megabit/s. Regular hard drives (spinning rust) can do 100+ Megabyte/s. That translates to 838+ Megabit/s.

Additionally, USB 2.0 tops out at ~40 Megabyte/s user data because of protocol overhead and whatnot.

Using your hard drive with a USB 2.0 port would *severely* limit its performance. As Gantendo recommends, you should use a USB 3.0 hub instead.